# Remove objects from NSMutable array that match with objects from another NSMutable Array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, duplicates

Ok so:

- i have NSMutableArray 1

  - i also have NSMutableArray 2

I would like to remove all objects from array 1 that match with objects in array 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just opened the documentation, print NSMutableArray and check removing objects section...

> ```
> [array1 removeObjectsInArray:array2];
> ```